# classify different parts of an image with tensorflow within the single graph

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow

I have an image of a chess board and I want to process it with CNN in a tensorflow in a square-by-square fashion within a single computational graph.

Each image looks like this:

[image]

Assumig an image is 200 by 200 px, so each square is 25 by 25 px. I am trying to implement it in a following way:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 200, 200, 3], name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 64, 13])

weights = {
   "conv1_w": tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,3,32], stddev=0.1)),
   "conv2_w": tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,32,32], stddev=0.1)),
   ...
}

with tf.Session() as sess:

    squares = split_into_squares(X)

    # i want to run some kind of loop here 
    # in order to process each square on the board
    # how can I do it ?
    for square in range(64):
        pred = cnn(square, weights)

    cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(Y, pred)
    adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for batch in range(1000)
       x, y = get_batch()
       _, loss = sess.run(adam, cost, {X:x, Y:y})
```

There are total 64 squares on a chess board and each square can be occupied by 6 white pieces, 6 black pieces or being vacant, so the output of each `sess.run()` is tensor of shape `(batch_size, 64, 13)`.

`split_into_squares()` takes a batch of chess board images and reshapes it to a tensor with dimensions (batch_size, 64, 25, 25, 3), 64 is a number of square on a chess board, 25 is a width and height of each square, 3 is a number of channesl.

The exact implementation of a `cnn()` function does not matter, the important part is that it accepts neural network weights, processes a single square and returns a prediction tensor of shape `(batch_size, 13)`.

Given that setup, how can I run `cnn()` for each square withing the single computation graph ?

Comment: You can slice the image into 64 slices (X) but how do you intend to get the corresponding labels (Y) for each slice to train CNN ? Do you already have each cell level annotation for your chess board ?

Comment: @mujjiga, yes, I already do have labels for each square. ‘Y’ placeholder contains them.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_blocks
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Images size 400 x 400
IMG_SIZE = 400
# No:of Chess Board Images
N_IMAGES = 3 

# Generator that generates one batch of images with the 
# corresponding labels
def generate(batch_size=32):
    # Using same image again and again 
    image_paths = ["4sEvs.jpg"]*N_IMAGES
    k = IMG_SIZE//8
    images = np.zeros((len(image_paths)*64, k, k, 3))
    for i, p in enumerate(image_paths):
        # Read image
        img = cv2.imread("4sEvs.jpg") 
        # slice the image into 64 slices and store it in numpy array
        images[i*64:i*64+64] = view_as_blocks(img, block_shape=(k, k, 3)).reshape(64,k,k,3)

    # dummpy labels
    y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(13, size=(len(images),1)))

    while True:
        for i in range(0, len(images), batch_size):
            # Generate a batch of train (data, labels)
            yield (images[i:i+batch_size], y[i:i+batch_size])

k = IMG_SIZE // 8

# Sample Model architecture 
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', 
    input_shape=(k,k,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(13, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer='adam',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32
# Train for 10 epochs
model.fit_generator(generate(batch_size), epochs=10, 
    steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(N_IMAGES*64/batch_size))
```

Code is explained in comments.

Comment: I appreciate for the effort, but that is not going to help me. I want to process a full image of the chess board withing a single graph. I do not want to split it to a 64 separate images and process them independently.

Comment: @koryakinp `for square in range(64): pred = cnn(square, weights)` but is this what you are doing

Comment: I am not doing it. I do not know how to do it and that is the principal of the question: how to convert that loop withing a computational graph of a Tensorflow.

Comment: and btw, what you have done can be done in one line with skimage.util.shape.view_as_blocks function.

Comment: @koryakinp I have added the model I was able to build.

Comment: I appreciate the effor, but again, that is not what I am trying to solve. I do not want to split an image of the chess board to a 64 small images of individual squares and process them 64 times. I want to process the whole image of the chess board at once in a single computational graph.